# cmakefileapi-parser warning message about CMake in windows-VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

```
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

I'm learning C++ in windows-VSCode. When I use CMake to run a helloworld, it show this.
Maybe it has succeed, but I am really mind this [cmakefileapi-parser] message.
How can I set it correctly?

Comment: This warning refers to the version of the Code model used by the [CMake File API](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html#object-kind-codemodel). As seen in this link, CMake expects the code model to be 2.0. However, it looks like somehow version 2.1 is being used, so VSCode may not properly gather all of the information it needs about the generated CMake buildsystem. You might try deleting your CMake build folder manually, then re-starting the build from scratch in VScode. This may help resolve the issue.

Comment: After running the CMake configuration, I opened this file -> "build\.cmake\api\v1\reply\codemodel-v2-ab6f9cacd31dc7acf0c6.json", scrolled all the way down, and changed the value of "minor" from 1 to 0. When I clicked Build again, the warnings were gone. FYI, I don't know if this breaks something else or not, I just figured it out by trail and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with cmake version 3.18.0-rc1 (release candidate).

I you use the latest stable release of cmake (version 3.17.3) instead, the problem should disappear ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[According to the CMake authors](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1341#issuecomment-652442662), version 2.1 of the CMake File API is completely backward-compatible with version 2.0, which is the latest version that your VSCode version knows about. So this warning can be safely ignored. There is already a fix in for the next version of the CMake addon, so this warning will go also go away when the next version of that addon is released.